# Merge specific columns in UI Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

I have a ui grid where i require to merge some of the middle columns. It should look something like below :

```
Name   | Address  | Comment  | Job  |  College | Married
----------------------------------------------------------
Keshvi | India    | New      | Not applicable  | No
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I am currently using rowTemplate.

```
function rowTemplate() {
    return  '  <div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in grid.appScope.customiseRowsDeletedBy(colContainer.renderedColumns) track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }"  ui-grid-cell></div>' +
        '  <div class="other-override-background" >{{row.entity.job}}</div>' +
        '  <div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in [colContainer.renderedColumns[5]]) track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }" ng-style="{position:\'absolute\, display:\'block\'}" ui-grid-cell ></div>' 
        '</div>';
}


$scope.customiseRowsDeletedBy = (arr) => arr.slice(0, 2);
```

however, my output looks something this :

```
Name   | Address  | Comment  | Job  |  College | Married
----------------------------------------------------------
Keshvi | India    | New      | Not applicable  | 
----------------------------------------------------------
No
----------------------------------------------------------
```

The third div shifts the content down.

Any idea how to go about?

Comment: There seems to be one `</div>` too many in your rowTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

TableData objects have a property called 'ColSpan' that you can use.

```
    document.getElementById("myTd").colSpan = "2";
```

I'm not too familiar with rowTemplate but perhaps it has a similar property.

Comment: the grid has been created dynamically and belongs to div DOM. So, colspan is not allowed. @RippStudwell